Are particles emitted with the same kinetic energy regardless of the radioisotope?
When radioisotopes emit radiation, such as alpha and beta particles, they are easily stopped by a thin sheet of aluminum. Those same particles, however, are also capable of achieving much higher penetration energies in a cyclotron or collider.
Do all radioisotopes, such as Polonium and Radium, emit particles with the same kinetic energy? I ask because radiation is often measured by the rate of particles emitted, but not by its penetration energy.

Concerning alpha decay, there is a relation between the kinetic energy of the emitted alpha particles and the lifetime of the parent nucleus known as the Geiger-Nuttall law. Interestingly, the kinetic energy varies by roughly a factor of two whereas the lifetimes span many orders of magnitude.

Reviewn the search results for  site:stackexchange.com OR site:libretexts.org OR site:wikipedia.org OR site:hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu physical quantities radioactivity

Alpha radioisotopes emit alpha rays at its own same characteristic energy. For example uranium-$238$ emits alpha particles having an energy $4.180$ MeV. All alpha particles from a given radioisotope have the same energy. Plutonium-$239$ emit alpha rays having all the same energy: $5.147$ MeV.
Beta radioisotopes are not like alpha radioisotopes. They emit beta rays having energies randomly situated between zero and a maximum published in the tables. For example, phosphorus-$32$ emits beta particles having an energy situated between zero and $1.718$ MeV as a maximum value. Tritium (hydrogen-3) emits beta particles having an energy situated between zero and a maximum of $0.018$ MeV. This behavior is due to the simultaneous emission of two particles, a beta particle, and also a neutrino, which has been rather hard to detect. The total available energy ($1.718$ MeV for P-$32$, and $0.018$ MeV for H-$3$) is randomly distributed between the beta particle and the neutrino.

Looking at this chart, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_particle#/media/File:Alpha_decay_energies_example.svg

It's hard to conceptually understand how much penetration energy a particle has in electron volts. Polonium 212 is like a wrecking ball. It looks like it could kick off a nuclear fission reaction by itself.

For reference, compare to the amount of energy required to ionize an atom: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionization_energy#/media/File:First_Ionization_Energy_blocks.svg Or convert it into a speed by equating an eV with the kinetic energy of the particle: $v=\sqrt{2KE/m}$ or convert into a light frequency, $\nu=E/h$.
